# Is it possible to distribute client iOS app with my distribution profile?

Tags: ios, apple-developer

I got one doubt, is it possible to distribute client iOS app with my distribution profile.

Comment: No, you have to create a new distribution certificate and provisioning profile.

Comment: @Jatin Patel, thank you. With the help of my developer account I need to create new distribution certificate and provisioning profile. Am I right.

Comment: Yes, You have to create new with following by this ~~> https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808748-iOS-Creating-a-Distribution-Certificate-and-p12-File

Answer (score 1):

You can distribute any iOS app with your profile. The profile should contain app id which is created in your account. So create app id matching the bundle id of the app in Xcode (if this bundle id has already been registered as app id in a different account then the bundle id should be changed) and then create a profile with your certificate and the newly created app id. That's it

Comment: thank you very much. Can you please explain little bit for me.

Comment: Sure. What precisely would you like to know?

Comment: The profile should contain app id which is created in your account.  which means I need to register that in my developer account like new app. Am I right.

Comment: 1. You can make new app id (unless this id has never been registered on a different account) and then create new profile. 
2. If for some reason you already have an app id and a profile corresponding to it and you need to use exactly this profile then you need to change app's bundle id to the app id used by this profile

Answer (score 1):

An app ID is a string used to specify an app, or set of apps. An app ID's primary use is to specify which apps are authorized to be signed and launched.

An app ID has two parts: the team ID followed by the bundle ID search string. The team ID is a 10-character string generated by Apple. Each development team is assigned a unique team ID used to identify all your apps. A bundle ID search string is traditionally a reverse-domain-name style string.

The following guide will show you create an App ID in the iOS provisioning Portal. To create an App ID, you need to have an Apple Developer account and be a member of the iOS Developer Program.

Step 1. Go to the Apple Developer Center

Log in Apple Developer Center, then click "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".

Step 2. Create New App ID

Click "Identifiers" under iOS Apps

Click on the "+" sign near the top right corner to add a new App ID. In the next screen you will be asked to create the App ID you want to use as well as the description you want to give it.

**Note: copy and save the Bundle Identifier you created because you will need to enter it into the iCreateApp when publishing your app.**

After that you will be brought to the confirmation screen. Hit submit once you looked over it.

Click "Submit" and it will create the App ID.

Step 3. Enter the App ID

Open iCreateApp, enter the bundle identifier (App ID Suffix) into App ID field.

After all the above process follow steps: https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808748-iOS-Creating-a-Distribution-Certificate-and-p12-File

Comment: is ti possible to release multiple apps with different bundle id's and same app id.

Comment: By using bundle ID you can create only single app ID so it is not possible to do that

Comment: Actually you wrote An app ID is a string used to specify an app, or set of apps. Thats why I'm asking.

Comment: You can create a wildcard app ID which might be what you're thinking of so that you've just got one provisioning profile for a suite of apps. See the Apple docs on it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ApplicationDevelopmentOverview/ConfigureYourProject/ConfigureYourProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011186-CH6-SW8